# which file is the  js error in and how to correct it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
http://www.idcspy.com/asp-hosting.html
```

when loads over the page , at the bottom of the  IE broswer window. it shows an alert(the page has an error), it's an javascript error.but i don't know which js file has the error in and how to correct it. thank you,

Comment: This is an English speaking site. Please could you translate the error message.

Comment: If you double click the exclamation mark, it will show you a window with the line and the js file that is causing the error, and the error too.

Answer (score 2):

Error appears in http://www.idcspy.com/sites/all/themes/idcspy/js/ZeroClipboard.js

Comment: More specifically it appears in line 14 : `if (!thingy.addClass) {` because variable `thingy` is null.

Comment: you're right. i see the error tips by the firebug. but how to  correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Developer tools, to find and debug the error

```
IE: Press F12
Firefox: Downlaod addon known as Firbug
Chrome: Right click -> Inspect Element to get started or (Ctrl + Shift + J)
```

Comment: i have konwn where the error is. but don't know how to correct it.could you do me a favor thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if thingy is an object:

```
if( typeof thingy=='object' && !thingy.addClass){/*statements*/}
```

Comment: i am sorry, it can't work. i know why it's shows the error.if the page doesn't has the flash, it will show the error.